# How to assign global view data for only an area?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, view

I have a dillema, I need to assign global view data to only a specific area of my mvc3 application. In this area I also have a base controller that inherits from a parent base controller in the root directory. I have not been able to assign the global view data in the constructor because it seems the base controller's properties were not yet initialized. Can someone please recommend me the proper way to do this or point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

The solution was:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
      // Logic
}
```

in my base controller.